# Dog like alien creature with telepathic and telekinetic abilities

Tags: story-identification, books, aliens

I can't remember much about it but I am looking for a science fiction story about a woman who is camping or something similar on a planet that has been marked as having no sentient beings living on it. She encounters a dog like creature who can communicate using telepathy and can move things using telekinesis. She calls it Onyx as it is black in colour, and she tries to take it to someone as proof that there are sentient beings on the planet.

Unfortunately I can not remember when I read it, can't even tell you if it was in the last 10 years or 20 years... I know it was a book, but more than that I have no idea.

Comment: Elements of this suggest "The Rowan" by anne mccaffrey, but I don't think that's it. It nags at my brain, which means I've read it or very similar.

Comment: I checked it out just in case, but no it isn't it. Don't think I'm ever going to remember it or find anyone who knows what book it is...will keep trying though!

Answer (score 2):

A Fire Upon the Deep (Vernor Vinge).

Comment: Could you [edit] this to explain how it matches? The work name is the most important but making it a good answer by explaining how it matches is a lot better.

Comment: Note that the Tines were not telekinetic, and communicated using sound, not telepathy.